# Postgres + Hibernate - How to create a primary key with MATCH FULL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, primary-key

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html
You have tons of options when creating a table's primary key in postgres. One of which is:

`REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ] [ MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE ]`

With that in mind, i have an entity Employee:

```
Employee
   String Neighborhood ID
   String Hunting ID
   String Fishing ID
   Rest of columns...
```

We want these to be the key `(neighborhoodId, huntingId, fishingId)` and we want a MATCH FULL primary key so that `(100, null, 100)` and `(100, null, 100)` will cause a validation constraint.

How do you do that in the hibernate entity lingo?

Comment: I realize that my understanding of MATCH FULL was wrong. that is only for FK. Is there something that works like this for a normal constraint?

Comment: primary keys (or parts of it) cannot be NULL at all, by definition http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS